# add text between buttons in the footer of semantic:footerCustomActions

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

i'm looking for a way to add a text between the button of 'semantic:negativeAction' and the button of 'semantic:positiveAction' in the footer of a semantic content within a semantic page of 'sap.f.semantic' .

```
<semantic:positiveAction>
        <semantic:PositiveAction  text="+"/>
    </semantic:positiveAction>



    <semantic:negativeAction>
        <semantic:NegativeAction text="-" />
    </semantic:negativeAction>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using customFooterContent aggregation in semantic page for footer

```
<semantic:customFooterContent>
                        <Button text="Approve" type="Accept" press="onAcceptPress"/>
                        <Label text="Test Text between two buttons"></Label>
                        <Button text="Reject" type="Reject" press="onRejectPress"/>
                    </semantic:customFooterContent>
```

Link:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.semantic.SemanticPage

Comment: yeeah i've tried that before but it didn't work maybe cuz i am using the SAP.f.semantic

Comment: Hi, sorry to ask but is there any specific reason you want to use sap.f.semantic page? If you definitely need to use it I dont think so you can place anything in between, you can place it on right which is standard .. using aggregation for same called "footerCustomActions".

Comment: i've created a project based on the template  masterdetails so now i wanna modify it

Comment: Let me know if you need anything. Happy to help.